# How to access Laravel Folder in Google Cloud

Tags: laravel, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I received an error on my Laravel App

> /app/storage/logs/laravel-2020-02-20.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

So I google the error, and I discovered it a permission error.

> chmod -R 775 storage
>
> chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache

Apparently, this fixes the error, but anytime I tried to run the command in the cloud console. It keeps saying

> No directory found.

Can someone advice me on how to access storage directory.

Comment: In wich directory are you running the command?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ In Google Cloud Shell

Comment: But are you in your project root folder? Can you run `pwd` to know the absolute path?

Comment: It returned `home/myusername`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the tags, I can tell it is GAE flex on GCP. Flex gives you SSH access, but it is not advisable to execute read/write operations directly on the Instances as they are preemptive - can be restarted anytime by GCP. So any command you execute will have to be repeated whenever a new instance starts, which will of course defeats the purpose of scalability on GAE flex.

Try this instead:

On the composer.json file in your project directory, add the follow to the scripts:

```
        "post-install-cmd": [
       "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
       "@php artisan optimize",
       "chmod -R 755 storage bootstrap\/cache" ]
```

For more info, check this community link: https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-flexible