# Permission Issue on GCP with Laravel Storage Folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, google-cloud-platform, laravel-4

Laravel when upload on Google Cloud Platform standard app engine environment. It always gives permission issues on deployment.
Some time it tries to access cache from the path which shows route of my local directory. I have added this code in my composer script, tried deleting my composer.lock file and reuploaded and then tested as well.

```
  "post-install-cmd": [
      "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
      "@php artisan optimize",
      "chmod -R 755 storage bootstrap\/cache" 
  ]
```

Even error shows my local directory path!!!!!!!! I have already added environment variables on
yaml as well.

```
  APP_STORAGE: /tmp
  VIEW_COMPILED_PATH: /tmp
```

```
ErrorException: file_put_contents(/media/riyo/64984189-3b2b-43bd-827f-3febb9e673a4/Havn/microservices/orders-microservice/storage/framework/cache/data/5f/79/5f79ca28c5f23bb2bdee5c894f207355b5536cf9): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Nothing seems to work i have switched to flex environment and tried as well! Anyone has solution for this issue?

Comment: From what you've shown, it doesn't look like a permission issue as it would show error permissions. The error you posted is more of a configuration issue. It seems the path/directory you created doesn't exist.
You can check these guides on how to deploy Lavarel:

https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-standard
https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-flexible

Comment: The issue is it shows directory of my local environment! I have already specifie /tmp directory for compiled views which is not beign overrided!

Comment: You can check this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60331089/how-to-access-laravel-folder-in-google-cloud
and this guide for help:
https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-flexible